# _resource_mismatch_handler_ is not gettingon WSO2 esb 5.0.0

Tags: api, error-handling, wso2-esb

I am trying to  implement the Error handling as recommened by WSO2 by using _resource_mismatch_handler_ sequence.

I created this sequence and deployed on  WSO2 ESB. There is no error in creation .

But sequence is not getting invoked when call non-existing api and I still get 202 status.

Any pointer to the issue will highly appreciated.

Thanks ,
Mahesh Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this detailed blog regarding how to set your requirement http://sajithr.blogspot.com/2015/02/reason-for-wso2-esb-returns-202.html